# Block Update and Delete operations on a AS400 file

Tags: ibm-midrange

Is there any way to block update and insert operation for a user on a file in AS400? Even if we give the SQL query for Delete or Update Query for that file, the file shouldn't give the authority to delete. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: You can set 'Allow update/delete operation' to *NO, while creating physical files.

Comment: I am trying to create file using CREATE TABLE command. So, is there any way I can block by using any CL commands like CHGPF?

Comment: I don't think CHGPF would help so. If you are the object's owner, you could try GRTOBJAUT to grant permission to another user.

Comment: We can grant Authority using GRTOBJAUT, but how do I remove the authority to Delete and Update?

Comment: RVKOBJAUT command is used to revoke authority from the objects. Beware before using these commands. Refer to example 3 of this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/rvkobjaut.htm

Comment: I tried that Vishal. The User Profiles which I am using has *ALLOBJ authority. So, I think it will not work. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are a whole range of permissions available to users of IBM i. So the short answer is Yes, you can do that. But there isn't any way to answer how here as the number of possibilities can fill a book, In fact it does fill many books. But the short of it is that you can use the basic SQL GRANT statement or even IBM i authorities. The long of it is that you need a security strategy, and then you can secure all of your objects and user profiles according to that strategy. IBM has a whole section of its Knowledge Center devoted to security. Maybe start there. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahg/rzahgicsecurity.htm

Comment: I tried REVOKE DELETE ON FILE1 FROM USER. I am able to delete records even after using that.

Comment: There are things that can override this. For example if your users all have *ALLOBJ, then there is nothing that can be done, or if your program adopts owner authority, or if you are at security level 20. There is a lot to security on IBM i, which is why this is not a good question for Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the documentation, or if you don't have a good understanding of security on IBM i, hire an expert to get a plan.

Comment: IBM i security is complex, and highly configurable. Without an intimate knowledge of your specific security setup, no one here will be able to answer your question. What you want can be done, but you may need to start at the beginning with an all inclusive security plan.

Comment: Also understand that though a specific user might not have authority to DELETE a record, if PUBLIC has DELETE authority, then all users have DELETE authority!

Comment: Yes, The user profiles which I am using has *ALLOBJ authority. So, as you said, Revoke is not working. I will go through the documentation once. Thank you very much.

Comment: At some point you need to understand that no regular user on your system should have any special authorities. Some folks give *ALLOBJ because they don't feel like managing IBM i security. This is a lazy way to go about it because it just gives those folks authority to every object on the system. Other special authorities give authority to perform certain potentially sensitive tasks like saving and restoring objects, or cancelling jobs or viewing other's spool files.

Comment: Rather than performing a proper security plan, everyone is given access to everything. Now your system is insecure despite the claims that IBM i is the most secure system on the planet. If you are new to this, I suggest you get help from a partner because reading the manuals will be a little like trying to drink from a fire hose.

Answer (score 0):

Security Rule 1 don't invent your own security.

Get started.

**Step 1 take everything  away from public.**
SQL

```
REVOKE ALL ON myfile.mylib FROM PUBLIC;
```

*I'm just saying access control by individual user is not a good practice.  Make the user a member of a group like TEMPS and block out the TEMPS group.  It makes me think Nepotism blocking a specific user.*

**Step 2 take everything away then add what group needs**

```
revoke all on myfile.mylib from temps;
GRANT INSERT ON MYLIB/MYFILE TO TEMPs;
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you can't remove *ALLOBJ from this person, I think one answer is to use Exit Points.  I highly recommend hiring someone to do this for you, but here is a good introduction: https://www.helpsystems.com/resources/articles/ibm-i-exit-points-what-they-are-and-when-use-them

Another possibility is to use Row and Column Access Control (RCAC)  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahf/rzahfrcactitle.htm